# Multiple Where conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause

Having trouble getting this syntax right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM metadata 
WHERE (meta_key = 'school' AND meta_value = 'Some School') 
AND WHERE (meta_key = 'hidden' AND meta_value = '1')
```

Its failing at line 4...

**UPDATED:**
Table looks like this:

```
meta_id - id - meta_key     - meta_value
1         1    school         Some School 1
2         1    hidden         0
3         2    school         Some School 2
4         2    hidden         1
5         3    school         Some School 3
6         3    hidden         0
7         4    school         Some School 4
8         4    hidden         0
9         5    school         Some School 5
10        5    hidden         1
```

**UPDATED:** I have a related, extended here [Does row exist and multiple where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982099/does-row-exist-and-multiple-where)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a second `where`, and the second `and` was probably intended to be an `or`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM metadata 
WHERE (meta_key = 'school' AND meta_value = 'Some School') 
OR (meta_key = 'hidden' AND meta_value = '1')
```

(the reason I think you wanted an `or` is because otherwise you have a conjunction of contradictory clauses `meta_key = 'school' AND meta_key = 'hidden'`, which is always false).

**EDIT** : In response to OP's comment about the results he is trying to get, here is a different query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.id 
FROM metadata m1
join metadata m2 on m1.id = m2.id
WHERE (m1.meta_key = 'school' AND m1.meta_value = 'Some School') 
AND (m2.meta_key = 'hidden' AND m2.meta_value = '1')
```

Now the conjunction clauses are no longer contradictory, because they refer to two different rows `m1` and `m2`.

Comment: There are several rows with the same id but differing school and hidden keys, I need to find if a school by name and find out if its hidden

Comment: @daidai you need an entirely different query then. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple WHERE clauses. I think what you mean is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM metadata 
WHERE (meta_key = 'school' AND meta_value = 'Some School') 
    OR (meta_key = 'hidden' AND meta_value = '1')
```

Comment: Darn, @dasblinkenlight beat me to it :)